# Calculate bounding box of a position on map in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

How can I calculate South West and North East coordinates from a position. I do not have the MKMapView. I need to calculate solely on the basis of CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
#define DEGREE(RADIANS) (180/M_PI) * RADIANS

#define RADIANS(DEGREE) (M_PI/180) * DEGREE

    double lat = [[_locManager location] coordinate].latitude;

    double lon = [[_locManager location] coordinate].longitude;

    double R = 6371; // earth radius in km

    double radius = 0.5; // bounding box spacing from current location in kilo meters

    double y2 = lon + DEGREE(radius/R/cos(RADIANS(lat)));

    double y1 = lon - DEGREE(radius/R/cos(RADIANS(lat)));

    double x2 = lat + DEGREE(radius/R);

    double x1 = lat - DEGREE(radius/R);
```

x1, y1 is South West latitude and longitude and x2,y2 is North East latitude and longitude